# SQL query (~5 tables join if possible)?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have those MySQL Tables:

```
products
id

products_content
product_id, lang, product_name, product_content

products_and_categories
product_id, category_id

products_categories
id, parent_id

products_categories_content
category_id, lang, category_name, category_content

products_and_prices
product_id, price_id

products_prices
id

products_prices_content
price_id, lang, description, weight, price, currency
```

How to select all products from category with id 5 (for example) and all prices for every single product? Is it possible with single query?

Currently to select all products from category, I'm using (CodeIgniter):

```
    $this->db->select('*')
        ->from('products')
        ->join('products_content', 'products_content.product_id = products.id')
        ->join('products_and_categories', 'products_and_categories.product_id = products.id')
        ->where(array('category_id' => $category_id, 'lang' => $lang));
```

Comment: nothing. I know how to do it, but with few methods. Just looking for simple way with complex single query.. if it is posible :)

Comment: You can always write a normal query using `$this->db->query('SELECT ...')->result()` using sub-queries if they are necessary.

Comment: Can't you just join the `products_and_prices` and `products_prices` tables to the query you have set up already?

Comment: as you want to diferent entites, products, and prices, its a big overhead to include all product data in each price row, its better to run 2 querys

Comment: MrSlayer, there is multiple prices for each product..

Comment: @ka-spot I think that your code it's ok, it's simple and readable

Comment: Puggan Se, how with 2 queries ? I'm thinking to do it with one query for all products and one query for all prices for each product... but with pagination (100 products per page) this is at least 101 queries per click. Just looking for less queries way..

Comment: figured how to do it with only 2 queries.. 1 all products and 2 all prices, then I'll do multi array with products and prices.